# client ID in okta not showing

Tags: oauth, auth0, okta

I am unable to find the client Id from the applications section in the SWA(Secure Web Authentication) method, in okta.

In most of the online forums client ID in the general section of the app is evident but in case of my app the client ID is not visible.

Comment: You need to create an OpenID Connect app to get a client ID.

Answer (score 1):

SWA was developed by Okta to provide Single Sign-On for applications that don't support federated sign-in methods. In your case, it looks like you want to use OpenID Connect (OIDC) integration method instead of SWA as client id is relaed to OIDC

You can use the following steps to create a OIDC application in Okta:

1. In the Admin Console, go to Applications > Applications.
2. Click Create App Integration.
3. To create an OIDC app integration, select OIDC - OpenID Connect as the Sign-on method.
4. Choose what type of application you plan to integrate with Okta. Select either Web Application, Single-Page Application, or Native Application.
   Click Next.

After the application is created, a client ID would be generated and displayed in application settings.